# How can I convert T-SQL with aggregate function to LINQ?

Tags: linq, t-sql

I have a complex script with T-SQL and I couldn't convert it to LINQ syntax:

```
SELECT cc.ContractID,
       Max(CASE WHEN cc.CompanyID = vc.CompanyID THEN vc.CompanyTitle END) AS CompanyID,
       Max(CASE WHEN cc.ContractorID = vc.CompanyID THEN vc.CompanyTitle END) AS ContractorID
FROM   ConContracts cc
       JOIN ViewCompanies vc
         ON vc.CompanyID IN ( cc.CompanyID, cc.ContractorID )
GROUP  BY cc.ContractID
```

Can any one help me??

Answer (score 3):

I used [Linqer](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjdotaUvbzQAhXBCiwKHUC2CEoQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sqltolinq.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNECZ3RUdv8de_WcHSsn_xm16Mv34A&sig2=a2jaQFObAJvAmP3TKXCjpA) to try and convert this query and ended up with:

```
from cc in db.ConContracts
from vc in db.ViewCompanies
where
  vc.CompanyID == cc.CompanyID ||
  vc.CompanyID == cc.ContractorId
group new {cc, vc} by new {
  cc.ContractID
} into g
select new {
  g.Key.ContractID,
  CompanyID = g.Max(p => (p.cc.CompanyID == p.vc.CompanyID ? p.vc.CompanyTitle : null)),
  ContractorID = g.Max(p => (p.cc.ContractorId == p.vc.CompanyID ? p.vc.CompanyTitle : null))
}
```

I'm by no means a LINQ expert, so don't know for sure whether this is a valid answer, but thought it might be helpful or interesting if it is at least functionally satisfactory, as it means you could have used Linqer to answer your question.

Comment: Both of them is correct but I have forced to used your code because I need to use more field in select scope and I must add these field in group as well.

Comment: I've removed my answer and upvoted yours because I forgot that I need `new [ cc, vc }` in order to make them available inside `select`. Please remove references to my answer, yours in good enough w/o them :)

Comment: @IvanStoev thanks, I've edited the answer accordingly. I feel a little bad because all I did was figure out how to use Linqer (I've never actually used LINQ or written a query for it before!), whereas you clearly understand whether this is a correct/valid solution.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an exact equivalent to your T-SQL, but I suspect it might give you the results you want.

I suspect that ContractID is unique to your ConContracts table and CompanyID is unique to the ViewCompanies table and hence the max is only added because you need it if you are using group by.

So, if your tables are defined correctly you can do something like

```
(from cc in ConContracts
select new
{
    cc.ContractID,
    CompanyID    = cc.Company.CompanyTitle,
    ContractorID = cc.Contractor.CompanyTitle
}
```